Can't get Session Timeout working after change from OpenIdConnect
I have a Dot.Net 4.8 project that has currently migrated to using Owin for Authentication, but Session Timeouts don't work any more.
This was working when the app used OpenIdConnect, but I can't figure out how to replace (or rewrite) the OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications part.
My old startup.cs file had the following code:
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            CookieManager = new SystemWebCookieManager(),
            CookieHttpOnly = true,
            CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.Always,
            ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Convert.ToInt32(_authSessionTimeout)),
            SlidingExpiration = true
        });

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                // Sets the ClientId, authority, RedirectUri as obtained from web.config
                ClientId = _clientId,
                Authority = _authority,
                RedirectUri = _redirectUri,
                ClientSecret = _clientSecret,

                // Do not use the token lifetime; this setting overrides the expiration of the auth cookie.
                UseTokenLifetime = false,

                // PostLogoutRedirectUri is the page that users will be redirected to after sign-out. In this case, it is using the home page
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = _postLogoutRedirectUri,
                Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenIdProfile,

                // ResponseType is set to request the code id_token - which contains basic information about the signed-in user
                ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken,

                // OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications configures OWIN to send notification of failed authentications to OnAuthenticationFailed method
                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                    AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed,
                    RedirectToIdentityProvider = ctx =>
                    {
                        // Prompt the user to login each time
                        ctx.ProtocolMessage.Prompt = "login";

                        // force re-authentication if the user hasn't logged in the last 15 minutes
                        ctx.ProtocolMessage.MaxAge = _authSessionTimeout;

                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
                }
            }
        );

Meanwhile, the new code (which I didn't write as I'm not well-versed on authentication code) looks like this:
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            CookieManager = new Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.SystemWebCookieManager(),
            CookieHttpOnly = true,
            CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.Always,
            ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Convert.ToInt32(_authSessionTimeout)),
            SlidingExpiration = true
        });


        // Get an TokenAcquirerFactory specialized for OWIN
        OwinTokenAcquirerFactory owinTokenAcquirerFactory = TokenAcquirerFactory.GetDefaultInstance<OwinTokenAcquirerFactory>();

        // Configure the web app.
        app.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(owinTokenAcquirerFactory,
                                       updateOptions: options => { });

        // Add the services you need.

        owinTokenAcquirerFactory.Services
             .Configure<ConfidentialClientApplicationOptions>(options =>
             {
                 options.RedirectUri = _redirectUri;
                 options.TenantId = Tenant;
                 options.ClientSecret = _clientSecret;
                 options.ClientId = _clientId;

             })
            .AddMicrosoftGraph()
            .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

        owinTokenAcquirerFactory.Build();

I'm sure the issue is the missing 'Notification' section, but I can't figure out how to incorporate that in the new code.
Not sure I'm sharing enough info, but I'd appreciate any help or direction.

Looking at the code above, what is the value in using the new Owin approach vs the legacy OpenIdConnect approach?
